# How to convert SVG to canvas to PNG when there are multiple SVGs in a page

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas, svg

```js
var  formatAsPercentage = d3.format("%"),
  formatAsPercentage1Dec = d3.format(".1%"),
  formatAsInteger = d3.format(","),
  fsec = d3.time.format("%S s"),
  fmin = d3.time.format("%M m"),
  fhou = d3.time.format("%H h"),
  fwee = d3.time.format("%a"),
  fdat = d3.time.format("%d d"),
  fmon = d3.time.format("%b")
  ;
// Let's create a mock visualization

function dsPieChart(){

 var dataset = [
   {category: "apple", measure: 0.30},
       {category: "mango", measure: 0.25},
       {category: "pineapple", measure: 0.18},
       {category: "orange", measure: 0.0},
       {category: "peach", measure: 0.18}
       ]
       ;

 var  width = 400,
     height = 400,
     outerRadius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
     innerRadius = outerRadius * .999,   
     // for animation
     innerRadiusFinal = outerRadius * .5,
     innerRadiusFinal3 = outerRadius* .45,
     color = d3.scale.category20()    //builtin range of colors
     
     ;
var svg = d3.select("#pie")
      .append("svg:svg")              //create the SVG element inside the <body>
      .data([dataset])                   //associate our data with the document
          .attr("width", width)           //set the width and height of our visualization (these will be attributes of the <svg> tag
          .attr("height", height)
        .append("svg:g")                //make a group to hold our pie chart
          .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")")    //move the center of the pie chart from 0, 0 to radius, radius
    ;

var arc = d3.svg.arc()              //this will create <path> elements for us using arc data
         .outerRadius(outerRadius).innerRadius(innerRadius);
   
   // for animation
   var arcFinal = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadiusFinal).outerRadius(outerRadius);
 var arcFinal3 = d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadiusFinal3).outerRadius(outerRadius);

   var pie = d3.layout.pie()           //this will create arc data for us given a list of values
        .value(function(d) { return d.measure; });    //we must tell it out to access the value of each element in our data array

   var arcs = svg.selectAll("g.slice")     //this selects all <g> elements with class slice (there aren't any yet)
        .data(pie)                          //associate the generated pie data (an array of arcs, each having startAngle, endAngle and value properties) 
        .enter()                            //this will create <g> elements for every "extra" data element that should be associated with a selection. The result is creating a <g> for every object in the data array
            .append("svg:g")                //create a group to hold each slice (we will have a <path> and a <text> element associated with each slice)
               .attr("class", "slice")    //allow us to style things in the slices (like text)
               .on("mouseover", mouseover)
        .on("mouseout", mouseout)
        .on("click", up)
        ;
        
        arcs.append("svg:path")
               .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); } ) //set the color for each slice to be chosen from the color function defined above
               .attr("d", arc)     //this creates the actual SVG path using the associated data (pie) with the arc drawing function
     .append("svg:title") //mouseover title showing the figures
       .text(function(d) { return d.data.category + ": " + formatAsPercentage(d.data.measure); });   

        d3.selectAll("g.slice").selectAll("path").transition()
       .duration(750)
       .delay(10)
       .attr("d", arcFinal )
       ;
 
   // Add a label to the larger arcs, translated to the arc centroid and rotated.
   // source: http://bl.ocks.org/1305337#index.html
   arcs.filter(function(d) { return d.endAngle - d.startAngle > .2; })
     .append("svg:text")
       .attr("dy", ".35em")
       .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
       .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + arcFinal.centroid(d) + ")rotate(" + angle(d) + ")"; })
       //.text(function(d) { return formatAsPercentage(d.value); })
       .text(function(d) { return d.data.category; })
       ;
    
    // Computes the label angle of an arc, converting from radians to degrees.
  function angle(d) {
      var a = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) * 90 / Math.PI - 90;
      return a > 90 ? a - 180 : a;
  }
      
  
  // Pie chart title   
  svg.append("svg:text")
       .attr("dy", ".35em")
       .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
       .text("Usage Domainwise")
       .attr("class","title")
       ;      


  
 function mouseover() {
   d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
       .duration(750)
           //.attr("stroke","red")
           //.attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
           .attr("d", arcFinal3)
           ;
 }
 
 function mouseout() {
   d3.select(this).select("path").transition()
       .duration(750)
           //.attr("stroke","blue")
           //.attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
           .attr("d", arcFinal)
           ;
 }
 
 function up(d, i) {
 
    /* update bar chart when user selects piece of the pie chart */
    //updateBarChart(dataset[i].category);
    
    updateBarChart(d.data.category, color(i));
    updateBarStatusChart(d.data.category, color(i));
    
 }
// Create an export button
d3.select("#pie")
    .append("button")
    .html("Export")
    .on("click",svgToCanvas);

var w = 100, // or whatever your svg width is
    h = 100;

// Create the export function - this will just export 
// the first svg element it finds
function svgToCanvas(){
   debugger;
    var svg = d3.select("svg")[0][0],
        img = new Image(),
        serializer = new XMLSerializer(),
        svgStr = serializer.serializeToString(svg);

    data = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+window.btoa(svgStr);
    
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
 canvas.width = 400;
               canvas.height = 400;
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    img.src = data;
    img.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);
      var canvasdata = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      var pngimg = '<img src="'+canvasdata+'">'; 
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      a.download = "sample.png";
      a.href = canvasdata;
      a.click();
    };
};

 
}

dsPieChart();

var datasetBarChart = [
{ "group": "All","category": "seasonal", "measure": 63850.4963 }, 
{ "group": "All", "category": "allYear", "measure": 78258.0845 }, 
{ group: "apple", category: "seasonal", measure: 19441.5648 }, 
{ group: "apple", category: "allYear", measure: 25922.0864 }, 
{ group: "mango", category: "seasonal", measure: 9720.7824 }, 
{ group: "mango", category: "allYear", measure: 6480.5216 },
]
;



// set initial group value
var group = "All";

function datasetBarChosen(group) {
 var ds = [];
 for (x in datasetBarChart) {
   if(datasetBarChart[x].group==group){
    ds.push(datasetBarChart[x]);
   } 
  }
 return ds;
}


function dsBarChartBasics() {

  var margin = {top: 30, right: 5, bottom: 20, left: 50},
  width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  colorBar = d3.scale.category20(),
  barPadding = 1
  ;
  
  return {
   margin : margin, 
   width : width, 
   height : height, 
   colorBar : colorBar, 
   barPadding : barPadding
  }   
  ;
}

function dsBarChart() {

 var firstDatasetBarChart = datasetBarChosen(group);          
 
 var basics = dsBarChartBasics();
 
 var margin = basics.margin,
  width = basics.width,
    height = basics.height,
  colorBar = basics.colorBar,
  barPadding = basics.barPadding
  ;
     
 var  xScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, firstDatasetBarChart.length])
      .range([0, width])
      ;
      
 // Create linear y scale 
 // Purpose: No matter what the data is, the bar should fit into the svg area; bars should not
 // get higher than the svg height. Hence incoming data needs to be scaled to fit into the svg area.  
 var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
   // use the max funtion to derive end point of the domain (max value of the dataset)
   // do not use the min value of the dataset as min of the domain as otherwise you will not see the first bar
     .domain([0, d3.max(firstDatasetBarChart, function(d) { return d.measure; })])
     // As coordinates are always defined from the top left corner, the y position of the bar
     // is the svg height minus the data value. So you basically draw the bar starting from the top. 
     // To have the y position calculated by the range function
     .range([height, 0])
     ;
 
 //Create SVG element
 
 var svg = d3.select("#bar")
   .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .attr("id","barChartPlot")
      ;
 
 var svg = svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
      ;
             
 svg.selectAll("rect")
     .data(firstDatasetBarChart)
     .enter()
     .append("rect")
   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
       return xScale(i);
   })
     .attr("width", width / firstDatasetBarChart.length - barPadding)   
   .attr("y", function(d) {
       return yScale(d.measure);
   })  
   .attr("height", function(d) {
       return height-yScale(d.measure);
   })
   .attr("fill", "BLUE")
   ;
 
  
 // Add y labels to plot 
 
 svg.selectAll("text")
 .data(firstDatasetBarChart)
 .enter()
 .append("text")
 .text(function(d) {
   return formatAsInteger(d3.round(d.measure));
 })
 .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
 // Set x position to the left edge of each bar plus half the bar width
 .attr("x", function(d, i) {
   return (i * (width / firstDatasetBarChart.length)) + ((width / firstDatasetBarChart.length - barPadding) / 2);
 })
 .attr("y", function(d) {
   return yScale(d.measure) + 14;
 })
 .attr("class", "yAxis")
 /* moved to CSS      
 .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
 .attr("font-size", "11px")
 .attr("fill", "white")
 */
 ;
 
 // Add x labels to chart 
 
 var xLabels = svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + (margin.top + height)  + ")")
      ;
 
 xLabels.selectAll("text.xAxis")
    .data(firstDatasetBarChart)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d) { return d.category;})
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   // Set x position to the left edge of each bar plus half the bar width
         .attr("x", function(d, i) {
           return (i * (width / firstDatasetBarChart.length)) + ((width / firstDatasetBarChart.length - barPadding) / 2);
         })
    .attr("y", 15)
    .attr("class", "xAxis")
    //.attr("style", "font-size: 12; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif")
    ;   
  
 // Title
 
 svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", (width + margin.left + margin.right)/2)
  .attr("y", 15)
  .attr("class","title")    
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Overall")
  ;
  
  // Create an export button
d3.select("#bar")
    .append("button")
    .html("Export")
    .on("click",svgToCan);


}

dsBarChart();

var w = 100, // or whatever your svg width is
    h = 100;


function svgToCan(){
    // Select the first svg element
    debugger;
    var svg = d3.select("svg")[0][0],
        img = new Image(),
        serializer = new XMLSerializer(),
        svgStr = serializer.serializeToString(svg);

    data = 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,'+window.btoa(svgStr);
    
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
 canvas.width = 400;
               canvas.height = 400;
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    img.src = data;
    img.onload = function() {
      context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);
      var canvasdata = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      var pngimg = '<img src="'+canvasdata+'">'; 
      var a = document.createElement("a");
      a.download = "sample.png";
      a.href = canvasdata;
      a.click();
    };
};
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div id="pie"></div>
<div id="bar"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

No matter which selector I choose it always downloads the first SVG element.
I know it's because I am choosing `var svg = d3.select("svg")[0][0]` first element this way.
But I am calling two instances of function to avoid this, can somebody please suggest how I can choose the desired SVG element that I want while converting it to PNG.

Answer (score 1):

Use `selectAll()` method instead of `select()` in `svgToCan()` function there you will get all the list of svgs.

**Replace the function svgToCan(){} with these lines**

```
var arr=[];
    for(var i=0;i<d3.selectAll("svg").length;i++){
        arr=d3.selectAll("svg")[i];
        console.log(d3.selectAll("svg")[i]);
    }
     for(var j=0;j<arr.length;j++)
        var svg = arr[j],
        img = new Image(),
        serializer = new XMLSerializer(),
        svgStr = serializer.serializeToString(svg);
```

For your reference i have attached my **jsfiddle example**.

https://jsfiddle.net/achuakshuu/L92ngrrd/